# weird(probably) CSS rem calculation behaviour with animation

Tags: css, css-transitions

I was eager to see how the calculations happen with relative CSS length values. So I created this [pen](http://codepen.io/praveenpuglia/pen/KwQryw?editors=110). Here's the code for the for the ease.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="parent">
PARENT
    <div class="child">
    CHILD
        <div class="super-child">
        SUPER CHILD
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
div {
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  border:1px solid white;
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 0;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;

  /* Try this for compound em values */
  /* font-size:2em; */ 
  /* Notice how the calculation happens from parent to innermost child*/

  /* Try this for rem */
  /* font-size:2rem; */
}
```

When I uncomment, `font-size:2em` the transition works from the `parent` to the `super-child` and upon commenting it back it happens in the same order, from parent to super-child. As expected. Good.

For `font-size:2rem` upon uncommenting it, the font-size for all texts increases together as expected but upon commenting it back, the reduction in `font-size` happens from `parent` to the `super-child`.

I am wondering why? Since, `rem` values depend only upon the root element value, why does the engine calculate it that way? Shouldn't it have reduced their font-size together as it increased it for them?

NOTE - I tried the same in JSBin and it shows different behaviour there since *JSBin reloads the entire preview frame* after each change in CSS. Whereas in Codepen it happens as if only the CSS got updated without reloading the entire preview frame, much like opening up developer tools and enabling or disabling a property.

Comment: But even if it goes back to pixels, it should do that together isn't it? Since there is nothing to calculate there relatively

Comment: It seems that different browsers handle the animations differently. I get wildly different results on all major browsers on *both* em and rem sizes. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with how CodePen itself handles style transitions.

Comment: I am not sure if i should say "I am sad". That way I can't rely on transitions to happen in a particular order. Although this kind of transition may not be relevant at all but getting inconsistent results bother me.